# Swift / cornerRadius and masksToBounds lets UIImageView disappear

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITableViewController` with a `UIImageView`. The content is loaded with the following simple code.

```
@IBOutlet weak var avatarImageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    updateUI()
}

func updateUI() {

    backendless.userService.currentUser.retrieveProperties()

    avatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = avatarImageView.frame.size.width/2
    avatarImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    let imgURL = NSURL(string: (backendless.userService.currentUser.getProperty("Avatar") as? String)!)
    avatarImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(imgURL)

    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

The ImageView does not appear.

But if I delete the following code, the UIImageView will be set and displayed correctly.

```
avatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = avatarImageView.frame.size.width/2
avatarImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.:

### PS:

Xcode 8.0

Swift 2.3

Contrains for ImageView are set to 120*120

`sd_setImageWithURL` = `pod 'SDWebImage'`

[image]

Comment: this is just a guess but can you just change `width/2` to `width/2.0` and run once? it might be a problem of auto layout constraints also..

Comment: @M.K. no difference on `width/2.0` - the UIImageView still doesn't display

Comment: put a debugger and check whats the width just before this line..if it has value or not. because this code works everywhere. i don't think there is any problem with the code. i think problem with the sequence of the code and correct place to call it.

Comment: `print("width = \(avatarImageView.frame.size.width)")` sais 1.000 .... but i did set constraints to 150.... hmmmmm you may be right on your guessing...

Comment: but why is that?? Width Equals 120... why is it 1.000 with `print("width = \(avatarImageView.frame.size.width)")` inside `func updateUI()`?

Comment: i even checked.... see image

Comment: i guess this is because its inside UITableViewController. can you try same with normal UIViewController with a image and same code?

Comment: no need to try. it's working somewhere else in my code within UIViewController and UITableView.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123649/discussion-between-m-k-and-david-seek).

Comment: but why is that? whats the point in setting constraints then? ps i'm using static cells here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One obvious problem is that you are calling `updateUI` too soon. In `viewDidLoad`, there is no UI. The view has loaded but that is all; it is not in the interface and no layout has yet taken place. Your code depends upon `avatarImageView.frame`, but we do not yet know what that is. You have constraints on the image view, but they have not yet taken effect! Thus you should postpone this call until after the interface is present, e.g. `viewDidAppear` or at least `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. But of course then you probably only want to call it *once* (typed in browser, not tested, but it will be something like this):

```
var didConfigureUI = false
func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if !didConfigureUI {
        didConfigureUI = true
        updateUI()
    }
}
```

Comment: calling it in viewDidLayoutSubviews causes the app to freeze in an endless loop. my `print("width = \(avatarImageView.frame.size.width)")` within updateUI will be called infinity times. but other then that you're right. calling everything within viewDidAppear works

Comment: It is your job to put in a "flag" to prevent the recursive loop. You only want this code to run once, after all, right?

Comment: thank you @matt . i will keep that in mind and try to find more out about how to put in a flag. thank you for your help and effort tho

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded() // <- This will update your initial view frames
    updateUI()
}
```

What is happening is that in Xcode 8.0, by the time you hit viewDidLoad, the frame of all subviews of a controller is still x: 0.0, y: 0.0, w: 1000.0, h: 1000.0, so in effect you're making the corner radius of your avatar image view 500.0pt. When you call layout if needed, the correct frames will be calculated, and give you the value you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem with your controller. You have added the image view to a UITableViewController. That means constraint set to image view will not work if you use the frame in view did load. You need to change frame of the UIIMageView before use it or you need to use UIViewController. use the below code before using the frame of image view.

```
avatarImageView.frame.size.width = 120.0
avatarImageView.frame.size.height = 120.0
```

I think this will solve the problem. But you should use UIViewController if there is no special purpose of UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

```
“xy.view.layoutIfNeeded()”
```

needs to be called everytime i’m calling a property before the view has finished loading
for example imageView.view.layoutIfNeeded() to call for the height and widths values